# CustomTextbox in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

[image: Sample img]Hi friends basically i am a android developer. i am newbie in blackberry development. i need to create the custom text box with image button.

in the right corner of the text box, i want the small image button and it's click listener the text box field should be empty.

i Can create the Custom Text box and also draw bitmap inside the text box. but i can't catch the focus and listener to the image button. please help me

Please give some idea and samples.

I tried this...

MyApp.java Class:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
```

public class MyApp extends UiApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}

public MyApp() {
    pushScreen(new MyScreen());
}
```

}

MyScreen.java class:

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
public MyScreen() {
    super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
    setTitle("MyTitle");

    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(
            Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(
            Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm1 = new HorizontalFieldManager(
            Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    customManager ctm = new customManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

    customManager ctm1 = new customManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

    hfm.add(ctm);
    hfm1.add(ctm1);
    vfm.add(hfm);
    vfm.add(hfm1);
    add(vfm);
}
```

}

customManager.java Class:

```
public class customManager extends Manager implements FieldChangeListener {

private Textbox txt;
private Closebtn cls;

Bitmap bitmap;

protected customManager(long style) {
    super(style);

    // My Coustem TextBOX
    txt = new Textbox(300, 100);
    // My Coustem Button
    cls = new Closebtn();

    cls.setChangeListener(this);
    add(txt);
    add(cls);
}

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {

    setPositionChild(getField(0), 10, 10);
    layoutChild(getField(0), getField(0).getPreferredWidth(), getField(0)
            .getPreferredHeight());

    setPositionChild(getField(1),
            getField(0).getWidth() - (getField(1).getWidth()), getField(0)
                    .getHeight() / 2 - getField(1).getHeight() / 2);
    layoutChild(getField(1), getField(1).getWidth(), getField(1)
            .getHeight());

    setExtent(width, height);
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    txt.setText("");

}
```

}

Textbox.java Class:

```
public class Textbox extends Manager {
private int managerWidth;
private int managerHeight;
private int arcWidth;

private VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(
        NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | USE_ALL_WIDTH );
private EditField editField;
private Bitmap bagBitmap;

Textbox(int width, int height, long style) {
    super(style | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
    managerWidth = width;
    managerHeight = height;
    long innerStyle = style & (READONLY | FOCUSABLE_MASK); // at least
    if (innerStyle == 0) {
        innerStyle = FOCUSABLE;
    }
    editField = new EditField("", "", 10, innerStyle);

    arcWidth = editField.getFont().getHeight() & 0xFFFFFFFE; // make it even

    EncodedImage en = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("_text.png");

    bagBitmap = Util.getScaledBitmapImage(en, width, height);
    add(vfm);
    vfm.add(editField);
}

public void setFont(Font font) {
    super.setFont(font);
    editField.setFont(font);
    arcWidth = editField.getFont().getHeight() & 0xFFFFFFFE;
    updateLayout();
}



Textbox(int width, int height) {
    this(width, height, 0L);
}

public String getText() {
    return editField.getText();
}

public void setText(String newText) {
    editField.setText(newText);
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return managerWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return managerHeight;
}

protected void sublayout(int w, int h) {
    if (managerWidth == 0) {
        managerWidth = w;
    }
    if (managerHeight == 0) {
        managerHeight = h;
    }
    int actWidth = Math.min(managerWidth, w);
    int actHeight = Math.min(managerHeight, h);
    layoutChild(vfm, actWidth - arcWidth, actHeight - arcWidth);
    setPositionChild(vfm, arcWidth / 2, arcWidth / 2);
    setExtent(actWidth, actHeight);
}

protected void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.drawBitmap(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), bagBitmap, 0, 0);

    super.paint(g);
}
```

}

Closebtn.java Class:

```
public class Closebtn extends Field {

private Bitmap bitmap;

public Closebtn() {
    super(Manager.FOCUSABLE);

    EncodedImage en = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("close.png");

    bitmap = Util.getScaledBitmapImage(en, 50, 50);

}

protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
            bitmap, 0, 0);
}

protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    bitmap = bitmap;

}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    bitmap = bitmap;
}

protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time) {
    if (character == Characters.ENTER) {
        clickButton();
        return true;
    }
    return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
}

protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    clickButton();
    return true;
}

protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
    clickButton();
    return true;
}

protected boolean invokeAction(int action) {
    switch (action) {
    case ACTION_INVOKE: {
        clickButton();
        return true;
    }
    }
    return super.invokeAction(action);
}

public void setDirty(boolean dirty) {
}

public void setMuddy(boolean muddy) {
}

public void clickButton() {
    fieldChangeNotify(0);
}
```

}

Util.java Class:

```
public class Util {

public static Bitmap getScaledBitmapImage(EncodedImage image, int width,
        int height) {

    if (image == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getWidth());
    int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getHeight());

    int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(width);
    int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(height);

    int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32,
            requiredWidthFixed32);
    int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32,
            requiredHeightFixed32);

    image = image.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);

    return image.getBitmap();
}
```

}

My problem is i can't add more then one fields here  Pls help me..

Comment: You are adding both fields, but you are only able to see one because in your `Textbox` class, the manager is created with the flag `USE_ALL_HEIGHT`. Remove it and you should be able to see both. Also you forgot to add the buttons.

Comment: Hi Smith,Can u explain bit more i removed the USE_ALL_HEIGHT in the textbox class, and also i added both text box and button field in Custom manager class..

Comment: Now I read it again, it seems that you forgot to add hfm1 to vfm.

Comment: i added hfm1 also.... but i got same problem... i can view only one text box with button... cant see another one.. i dont know where have i made the mistake... did you run my code...

Comment: Try to update the posted code with your changes, and also show where and how are you instantiating Textboxes. You did a lot of custom development here, unlike the approach I recommended you in my answer. There might be some bugs somewhere you'll have to debug.

Comment: Smith i posted my full code here... for the bitmap use your own image and give me your thought

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13505/discussion-between-prakash-and-mister-smith)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this custom class:

```
public class TextFieldWithClear extends HorizontalFieldManager {
protected HorizontalFieldManager hfmEditTextPanel;
protected LabelField lblEditText;
protected EditField textField;
protected MyImageButton bitmapFieldClear;
int mHeight;
int mWidth;
String mLabel;

public TextFieldWithClear(String label, int width, int height) {
    super(FOCUSABLE);

    Border border = BorderFactory
            .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(2, 2, 2, 2));
    this.setBorder(border);
    Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setBackground(bg);

    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;
    mLabel = label;

    lblEditText = new LabelField(mLabel) {
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setColor(0x4B4B4B);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };
    add(lblEditText);

    hfmEditTextPanel = new HorizontalFieldManager(FOCUSABLE
            | VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR) {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            maxWidth = mWidth - 30;
            maxHeight = mHeight;
            super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setExtent(maxWidth, maxHeight);
        }
    };

    textField = new EditField() {
        // protected void layout(int width, int height)
        // {
        // width = mWidth - 50;
        // height=35;
        // super.layout(width, height);
        // //setExtent(width, height);
        // }
    };
    hfmEditTextPanel.add(textField);
    add(hfmEditTextPanel);
    bitmapFieldClear = new MyImageButton(
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn_delete_normal.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn_delete_focused.png"));
    bitmapFieldClear.setChangeListener(buttonListener);
    add(bitmapFieldClear);
}

public String getText() {
    String value = "";
    if (textField.getText().length() > 0)
        value = textField.getText();
    return value;

}

public void setString(String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        textField.setText(value);
    }
}

FieldChangeListener buttonListener = new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        textField.clear(0);
        textField.setFocus();

    }
};
public void onUndisplay()
{
    textField.setEditable(false);
}
public void onDisplay()
{
    textField.setEditable(true);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy to do just overriding `EditField`, so this is what I'd try:

- Use an horizontal manager (for instance, `HorizontalFieldManager` or other custom manager, perhaps with fixed column widths. This manager would have two fields inside: at left an EditField, at right a custom buttonfield.
- Set a `Background` to the manager. The bg would draw the green background as well as the blue border. You can use an scaled bitmap (have a look at [`BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/decor/BackgroundFactory.html#createBitmapBackground%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29)).
- Create a new `EditField` subclass, and override its `paintBackground` method so that it does nothing. If it does not work, try overriding `paint` so that it does only draw the text. This is the trickiest part.
- Create a custom `Buttonfield` subclass with the cross over gray circle image. You can read a good tutorial on how to do that [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/es-es/developers/deliverables/29251/Creating_a_custom_button_1676236_11.jsp). You also have available an already made `BitmapButtonField` in the [Advanced Ui Library](http://docs.blackberry.com/es-es/developers/deliverables/29251/About_the_advanced_UI_library_1626501_11.jsp). When the button is clicked, it would invoke `EditField.setText("")` on the EditField.

Comment: i have edited my question ... pls have look and give me your thought